# How degrade SMB through CMD

Tags: windows, smb

Is there a way for **downgrade** the **SMB** protocol to **SMBv1** through the CMD console?

I trying share my "*program.exemple*" using "**[impacket-smbserver](https://github.com/SecureAuthCorp/impacket/blob/master/examples/smbserver.py)**" but this error is displayed:

> "You can't connect to the file share because it's not secure. This
>   share requires the obsolete SMB1 protocol..."

Any help is more than grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to downgrade the connection, you need to enable SMBv1, by default it is disabled on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't do this. You should not use systems or software that do not support the later, more secure versions of SMB.

If you insist on doing this though, you'll need to use the following PowerShell command in an ELEVATED Poweshell session:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the powershell commands, see [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/detect-enable-disable-smbv1-smbv2-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server) link.